# PHP PDO insert using transaction doesn't show error

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, transactions

I have this code:

```
$Pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'password');

$options = = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_CURSOR           => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table (
            field_a,
            field_b
        ) VALUES (
            :field_a,
            :field_b
        )';

$Pdo->beginTransaction();

$Ps = $Pdo->prepare($sql, $options);

$Ps->execute(array(
    ':field_a' => 'Field A',
    ':field_b' => 'Field B',
    ':field_c' => 'Field C'
));

$Pdo->commit();
```

`$Ps-execute()` returns `false`, but doesn't show an error message telling that there are more columns than in the SQL specified.

In my real case i have more than one SQL statement, because of this i am using a transaction.

Someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You have `field_a,field_b` and binding two in your values. Then, you're executing for three thereafter. Is there no `field_c`?

Comment: Have you tried calling [PDOStatement::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) and [PDOStatement::errorCode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) after the failing query?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I did this knowingly, i am trying force PHP to trigger an exception instead of `execute()` return false

Comment: @HorusKol, Yes, it works, but i trying to force PHP to trigger an exception or error

Comment: Ok, I misread then. Did you try a (try/catch method) `try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage(); 
    }` - that's an example of course.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Yes, it works perfectly. I just would like to trigger an error if the SQL statement has less parameters than specified in the input array. Please see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php), there is a little note about this situation.

Comment: So, did that help or are you still looking for another method?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, The connection is okay, the SQL too, but there are more  **input_parameters** than in the SQL specified and an error isn't triggered, so i am trying to force an exception or error.

Comment: Got it. Ok, well that's a new one for me. That's about all I know to (hopefully) trigger and catch errors, other than `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` under the opening PHP tag. Wish I could help further.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Even doing what you suggested PHP didn't throw an exception or error. Please see the answer i sent and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the only solution i found is:

```
$Pdo->beginTransaction();

$Ps = $Pdo->prepare($sql, $options);

if( ! $Ps->execute(array(
    ':field_a' => 'Field A',
    ':field_b' => 'Field B',
    ':field_c' => 'Field C'
))){
    throw new Exception('Transaction failed: ' . implode(' | ', $Ps->errorInfo()));
}

$Pdo->commit();
```

Comment: If this works, great. The funny thing too being, I was thinking about "transactions", I should've followed my instinct ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, [I opened a ticket in PHP.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67557&thanks=4), let's see if it's a bug or a normal behavior.